# hostapd hotspot will only appear when ethernet is plugged in

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, hostapd, ap-hotspot

This has been driving me nuts all day.
Im using a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 on an odroid UX4 & [Wifi Module 4](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G141630348024) (RT5572N chipset)

What I want is: automatically start hotspot on boot + ability to hotplug ethernet cable whenever I need some temporary internet access, without disrupting the hotspot.

Followed the guide here exactly:

http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:xu4_wlan_ap#configure_access_point
http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:xu4_wlan_ap#configuration_for_wifi_module_4

It all seemed fine until I noticed that the ap/network gets created *only* if I plug in the ethernet cable. So:

So cold boot and no ethernet -> no hotspot. As soon as I plug in the ethernet cable, the hotspot appears and everything seems to work perfectly. I can connect to the hotspot from a different machine, access the outside internet, etc. I can also unplug the ethernet and it all continues to work fine. As soon as I reboot though, it wont work anymore.  So for some odd reason plugging in the ethernet is the trigger.

My suspicion is network manager is the culprit somehow.

I tried adding `allow-hotplug eth0` to the interfaces file (as one forum post suggested) but no difference.

**Edit**: Just to clarify. The host computer is an odroid ux4 which will be used in the field inside a la. It runs a webserver (amongst other things) and needs to be able to operate fully standalone (no internet). However, a some points (e.g., for updates, etc) I would just want to be able to plug in an ethernet cable (or USB modem for that matter) and then transparently be able to access the wider internet through the wifi connection. So in that case the system should just transparently forward requests to the internet over the wifi to one of the wired connections.

My network manager conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:7c:dd:90:86:96:8e  -> usb dongle
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

hostapd.conf (version 2.5)

```
# Interface
interface=wlan0

# driver
driver=nl80211

# Logging
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=3
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2

# CTRL-Interface
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0

# WLAN
country_code=KR
ssid=orangspy
hw_mode=a
channel=40
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
rts_threshold=2347
fragm_threshold=2346
preamble=1

# WPA2
wpa=2                            # WPA2 only
wpa_passphrase=xxxx
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=3                      # 1=wpa, 2=wep, 3=both
macaddr_acl=0
wmm_enabled=1
eap_reauth_period=360000
fragm_threshold=2346
rsn_preauth=1
rsn_preauth_interfaces=wlan0
wpa_group_rekey=600
wpa_ptk_rekey=600
wpa_gmk_rekey=86400

# N-WLAN
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[HT20+][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-20][TX-STBC]
require_ht=0
obss_interval=0
```

/etc/rc.local

Note: most information I find online uses bridge-utils instead of iptables commands to get the traffic forwarding to work. Dont know though what the best solution is.

```
if [ -f /aafirstboot ]; then
    /aafirstboot start
fi

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

exit 0
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:06:31:13:a0  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:6ff:fe31:13a0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:714 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:265823 (265.8 KB)  TX bytes:606661 (606.6 KB)

ip6tnl0   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1452  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:870 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:870 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:71560 (71.5 KB)  TX bytes:71560 (71.5 KB)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:dd:90:86:96:8e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7edd:90ff:fe86:968e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:9734 (9.7 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly trying to accomplish with this hotspot ? Are you running some kind of webserver on the machine creating the access point ?

The first link you've provided explains how to forward the traffic received on *wlan0* to the Internet via *eth0*. I wouldn't be too surprised if your access point wasn't then working when Ubuntu can't reach anything on that last interface. I'd try and skip the

> Setting for forwarding Internet over WIFI from eth0

part of your tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, see the edit that should clarify the use case. I will always talk to the host computer over wifi so it needs to run its own access point.   But at times I may want to briefly plug in an ethernet connection to the wider internet. At that point that wider internet connection should be shared through to the wifi network.

Comment: Got it ! Have you checked that the _hostapd_ daemon is automatically started on boot ? And have you tried manually bringing up/down your _wlan0_ interface (via sudo ifup wlan0 / sudo ifdown wlan0 ) ?

Comment: thanks. Ended up going with the create_ap script I found that Im very happy with so far (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

After log of googling and mucking around with config files I stumbled across the excellent create_ap script by oblique:

https://github.com/oblique/create_ap

This avoided any muddling with config files and worked out of the box.

As for this specific question about having eth0 transparently shared into the wifi. See this github issue for a suggested solution (have not been able to try it yet though):

https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/149

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in this situation the wlan0 interface will only come available after the eth0 has reached the timeout value that is set inside the /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf. So setting the timeout to for example 10 will make the wlan0 available after 10 seconds of trying to get an ip for eth0.